# Can I install Windows 8.1 after installing Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I've accidentally deleted Windows 8.1 when doing an attempt to install Ubuntu 14.04. But my grub does show me Windows (UEFI). 
When i put in my DVD, install disc for Windows 8.1, it doesn't react to the DVD, and it doesnt boot from the DVD when i reboot. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to select your dvd drive in your UEFI boot menu or give it higher priority in your UEFI boot order. Then it will boot. To find out which key to press, watch your screen instantly after switching your pc on. And grub might still have the old entry although the system is already gone. Running `sudo update-grub` should fix this. But maybe it is still there? Check your partitions using gparted, please.

Comment: In gparted i hvae 3 partions.

Comment: A bit more info. How are they called, file system, size? It would help me to see if there is any Windows left that maybe could be rescued or that could cause the boot trouble.

Comment: In gparted i have 3 partions. /dev/sda1, fat32,(mount point, boot/efi ) 512 MiB, used 4.36, flags: boot.. The other one is:/dev/sda2, ext4, mount point, /, 923,42 GiB, used 18.88, and the last one is /dev/sda3, linuxswap, 7.80 GiB, used 4.00 KiB. I hope you understand how i wrote that, i have the boot priority on CD/DVD ROM but nothing happens. And after i changed the boot order, the grub stopped coming up. @ByteCommander :)

Comment: Ok. There is no Windows system or data partition left, but the sda1 UEFI bootloader seems to be from Win. sda2 and sda3 are normal Ubuntu partitions. I wonder if you could just delete sda1 and put the boot flag on sda2, but I am not sure if this would make it better or worse. Sorry, but I have no experience with UEFI. I'll take a look at our chat room if I can find any expert. Please be patient...

Comment: @ByteCommander UEFI is like BIOS, so once you're in the UEFI menu you should be able to boot from the DVD from in there.
Maiken, can you take a picture (with a camera, not a phone) of your boot screen and post that in your question?